# Search Multiple Fields in Kibana /ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

In SQL i have

```
select Column1 , column2, column3 from Table where Column4 in ['a','b','c','d']
```

I'm trying to achieve the SQL statement in Kibana, I face challenge in writing the In condition.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": "X"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field2": "Z"
          }
        }
      ],

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting above result, you can either use `bool` query  `must` clause or `should` clause with `minimum_should_match` parameter. You can refer more about this from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Mapping created for your above columns is :

### Mapping

```
"mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "column1" : {
                "type":"text"
            },
            "column2" : {
                "type":"text"
            },
            "column3" : {
                "type":"text"
            }, 
            "column4" : {
                "type":"text"
            }
        }
    }
```

You can get your search results by two ways :

1. You can pass all your search values in `must` clause with `match` query. `Match` by default uses OR operator . So, it will match any document whose `column4` values matches any of these "a b c d". You can read about default operator of match query from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

### Query :

```
    {
    "_source": [
        "column1",
        "column2",
        "column3"
    ],
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "column4": "a b c d"
        }
    }
}
```

2. You can also you should clause with match query for every values. And restrict to only one match by using `minimum_should_match` parameter.

### Query 2:

```
 {
     "_source": ["column1", "column2", "column3"],
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "column4" : "a"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "column4" : "b"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "column4" : "c"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "column4" : "d"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match" : "1"
        }
    }
}
```

For the type of data you have for `column4` you can go with first query.

Comment: Query1 can be a simple match query instead of wrapping it in bool query.

Comment: @KumarV Yes, I missed that thing. Thanks for letting me know. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the value you want as an array.

In your example, write [a,b,c,d] instead of "X"

Answer (score 0):

We can use "query_string" query also to achieve the same. Since we are looking to match multiple values on the same field, query_string can be used with default_field set to the search field.

```
{
   "_source": ["column1", "column2", "column3"],
   "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "a OR b OR c OR d",
            "default_field" : "column4"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.